# react native ConfigUtils.configFilenameAsync is not a functio

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, fastlane

I am having some issues with react native, manual deployment using fastlane. I get the following error

```
[22:35:55] Unable to find an existing Expo CLI instance for this directory, starting a new one...
[22:35:55] ConfigUtils.configFilenameAsync is not a function
[22:35:55] TypeError: ConfigUtils.configFilenameAsync is not a function
    at _validateExpJsonAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@55.0.14\src\project\Doctor.js:203:40)
```

I searched everywhere in the net without finding any viable solution

Comment: can you post more information about what's going on to https://forums.expo.io/? also, please try installing the latest version of expo-cli: `npm i -g expo-cli`

Comment: I did install the latest version.

Comment: i don't believe so - the version of `@expo/xdl` mentioned in the error message in your post is 55.0.14, which is maybe 30 releases old, and from over 6 months ago: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@expo/xdl. `@expo/xdl` is a dependency of `expo-cli`

Comment: I am also getting same issue I have created RN App in version 0.59.8 in linux with expo 2.20.10 and its working fine in linux but same code base generating error 

`react native ConfigUtils.configFilenameAsync is not a functio`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this error when starting a brand new project with Expo. Seems to be just a weird bug in the expo cli. Updating `expo-cli` to the latest version (3.11.3) fixed it for me.